# Tridion 2011 SP1 OData Web Service

Tags: tridion

After following the install guide and unzipping the webservice.zip, copying the JDBC driver and config XMLs, when I try and access in a browser I see:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

A bit of digging suggests this is something to do with OAuth.
Any ideas?

Comment: check your cd_ambient_conf.xml file and try commenting out Security section.

Comment: Thanks Ram - that was it! Feel free to re-enter as an answer and Ill accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the OAuth security is enabled for the web services requests. You need to disable the security in cd_ambient_conf.xml file by commenting out the Security xml node section.

```
<!--
    <Security>
<RequestValidator>com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator</RequestValidator>
    <SharedSecret>sample_passphrase</SharedSecret>
    </Security>
-->
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could leave the security in place and actually pass a token in your requests. That seems wiser to me.

Comment: Thanks Peter - right now we just wanted to get it working. I can see from the docs a whole section about implementing authentication for the Content Delivery Web service or a Web site where this setting and the Accounts ones are utilised.

Answer (score 4):

That suggests that the request was made with an invalid token (or perhaps no token at all?).

Comment: Indeed - but why would this be occurring in a fresh install? I notice there's an "Account" node in the webservice conf - does this have to be set to an existing Tridion user?

Comment: Well did you pass a token in the URL? If not, you know the answer :) If you did, it was apparently no longer valid.